# EFI boot partition

Tags: partitioning, uefi

I have dual booted(win 7 + ubuntu 14.04) last year. But few days ago I can't boot to any OS, so I decided to install new Ubuntu 18.04 only. So, when I made a partition table and proceed to install, this lines are prompted. I'm not quite familiar with these.

> The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you
>   to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition
>   should be marked for use as “EFI boot partition” and should be at
>   least 35 MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition
>   mounted on /boot.
>
> If you do not go back to the partitioning menu and correct this error,
>   boot loader installation may fail later, although it may still be
>   possible to install the boot loader to a partition.

Comment: Does this computer have UEFI, which is the newer kind of BIOS? Did you use the MBR (msdos) partition table or the GPT partition table? Please edit the question above and add the new information in the question. If you ler Ubuntu installation erase everything (including all the data in all the partitions) then it will create all the partitions it needs.

Comment: See also: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu
 and  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: Are you using the default or manual setup? If you are using manual, please [edit] and add your partitioning setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Windows 10 (EFI boot) and installed Ubuntu 18.04 (Legacy boot) on second partition of the same drive. Ubuntu installer prompted the same message you are asking about. I've proceeded regardless the warning and both Windows and Ubuntu works just fine. (Note that swap partition is no longer needed in case of Ubuntu 18.04 if you are creating partitions manually.)